# Ubuntu 20.04 connects to wifi but no internet access

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dns, iwlwifi

Hi I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I don't know what I did accidentally so now I don't have internet access
first it was just connection to my ADSL and I solve it by manually adding ip and mask and dns
but now every wifi connection don't has internet access
I tried these commands but was not successful:

`modprobe -r iwlwifi`

`modprobe iwlwifi`

also:

`service NetworkManager restart`

here is the output of some commands:

````
~ ifconfig -a

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:6d:38:e0:0e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536

        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2643  bytes 207916 (207.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2643  bytes 207916 (207.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

        ether ea:df:c6:e3:de:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 86882  bytes 114770782 (114.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 58103  bytes 7138785 (7.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0




wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

        inet 192.168.1.150  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::fae4:e3ff:fe23:8d86  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f8:e4:e3:23:8d:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 216  bytes 18941 (18.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 742  bytes 76318 (76.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0```
````

```
~ nmcli 
wlp2s0: connected to ie_farzad
        "Intel 6 AX200"
        wifi (iwlwifi), F8:E4:E3:23:8D:86, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.1.150/24
        route4 192.168.1.0/24
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        inet6 fe80::fae4:e3ff:fe23:8d86/64
        route6 fe80::/64

docker0: connected to docker0
        "docker0"
        bridge, 02:42:6D:38:E0:0E, sw, mtu 1500
        inet4 172.17.0.1/16
        route4 172.17.0.0/16

usb0: disconnected
        "LG G2 Android Phone"
        1 connection available
        ethernet (rndis_host), EA:DF:C6:E3:DE:73, autoconnect, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlp2s0: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlp2s0"
        wifi-p2p, hw

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        interface: wlp2s0
```

I also tried with setting DHCP to automatically set ip and mask but the problem still exists

Comment: Is the modem not also the DHCP server?

Comment: Just my modem not any special DHCP server

Comment: Most modems as supplied by the ISP are by default also the DHCP server are you sure yours is not? It is nothing special it is a base function of the device. You would need to turn it of on purpose on most of them.

Comment: I mean yes my modem has DHCP server and every thing works good on windows but there isn't any separated DHCP server just my modem and its DHCP functionality works good on my mobile and windows

Comment: Maybe clarify your question and add that info via edit. Your question says you are doing things manually that the DHCP server usually handles. That is the real question, why this is not working.